# Where is initdb in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I want to reset my postgresql database back to its initial condition after install. Apparently initdb is the way to do this, but although the command has a man page, it doesn't seem to be anywhere on my Ubuntu 10.10 system.

Does anyone know how this is supposed to be done on Ubuntu?

Comment: initdb is somewhere on your system, PostgreSQL needs it to get started in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally I think you would be better off sticking with the Ubuntu specific commands, pg_lsclusters, pg_dropcluster, and pg_createcluster. These wrapper functions handle all of the filesystem layout pieces, and call initdb where necessary. It's not that you can't use the direct commands, but I've seen a lot of people get in to problems where they bypassed pieces of the regular ubuntu/debian config and then ran into problems when certain assumptions weren't met. You have a packaging solution, take advantage of it.

Comment: For server software this is absolutely ass-backwards.  *I* decide where my database data files go, not Ubuntu's overzealous re-packagers.  This kind of nonsense is Exhibit A for not ever running a server on Ubuntu.

Comment: @NoahYetter: the script doesn't *prevent* you from decide that; in fact, it gives you the `-d` switch for such purpose. There's plenty to rant about in Ubuntu, but having sane defaults shouldn't be one.

Answer (score 7):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=694887 suggests you want to be looking in `/usr/lib/postgresql/$postgres_version/bin` where you should also find createdb, createuser and similar, if you need them.

Substitute your postgres version as appropriate, obviously!

(As a more general tip: `locate initdb` would probably have furnished you with the answer. I don't have an Ubuntu machine with PG installed to check either the answer or this fact, though!)